# DIV tags (fields) that change positions

Tags: javascript, html

on my web form i have tree DIV tag fields.

can you give me which is best way to enable that those fields can switch their positions, without refreshing form?

i guess that with some javascript it's possible to do it?

tnx in adv!

Comment: Please, can you reformulate your question more precisely?

Answer (score 1):

If you want swap DIVs you should use the Javascript DOM methods like: `replaceChild`, `removeChild` etc.

look, for example at: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with JavaScript.
I recommend using jQuery, a JavaScript framework, which easily allows you to make objects like DIVs draggable and droppable in a cross-browser compliant manner. 
[jQuery UI Reference](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Try these